# Recursion within an Object

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures

I'm trying to convert the following object using recursion:

```
const objToConvert = {
 "article":[
   {
    "section@role":"Testing",
    "section":[
      {
        "title@id":"title test",
        "title":          {
          "content@id":"1",
          "content":"some simple content"
        }
      }
    ]
   }
  ]
};
```

to an object that looks like this:

```
const desiredObject = {
  type: "article",
  props: {
  },
  children: [
    {
      type: "section",
      props: {
        "section@role": "Testing"
      },
      children: {
        type: "title",
        props: {
          "title@id":"title test",
          "content@id":"1",
          "content":"some simple content"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
};
```

now I'm stuck when it comes to how I would handle the children. I've tried different things but I still can't get this to work right. I had an initial solution using an Array by accident instead of an object but I need this to be an Object.  I'm really lost on this..

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7dmowrdj/3/

```
function nodeAttributes(obj) {

    let attributeList = {};

    for (var attrib in obj) {
      const item = obj[attrib];

      if (item && item.constructor === String && attrib.indexOf("@") !== -1) {
        const attribVals = attrib.split("@");
        const attribName = attribVals[1];

        attributeList[attribName] = item;

      }

      if (attrib == "annotate")
        attributeList[attrib] = item;

    }

    return attributeList;

  }

 function walkObject(obj, compStructure, objAttributes) {

    for (var property in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {

          const curAttributes = nodeAttributes(obj[property]);

          const currentItem = {
            type: property,
            props: { ...objAttributes, ...curAttributes}
          };

         if (obj[property].constructor === Array) {              

              /* this work wont right */             
              //if (currentItem.children === undefined)
              //  currentItem.children = [];

              //this.walkObject(obj[property], currentItem.children, curAttributes);
              //compStructure = {...currentItem};

              walkObject(obj[property], compStructure, curAttributes);

          } else {

            walkObject(obj[property], compStructure, curAttributes);  
            debugger;

            if (!isNaN(parseInt(property)))
              compStructure = currentItem;

            debugger;

          }


        }
      }
    }
  }

  let compStructure = {};
  walkObject(objToConvert, compStructure, {});
  console.log(compStructure);
```

Comment: `"section@role"` should be a prop of `article`, not `section`

Comment: This is complex enough that I don't think the example is sufficient to describe the rules.  Are "article" and "section" in some way distinguished?  Just because they're arrays?  And why do the properties in "title" get promoted to be properties of their parent object?  Just because it's an object?

Comment: Yes exactly, just because they are arrays. And yes, the properties for title goto the parent because it's an object

Comment: should be `title` an array with objects?

Comment: @NinaScholz No it should not be

Comment: Is TKoL's comment correct?  If not, how would you know to place this inside "section"?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Not sure if this makes sense the way I'm explaining it but every level it traverses through I'm trying to grab the attributes (properties that are simply strings that contain "@" inside) and then I pass those as props. So, if we looked at article as we traverse through into first object and see section@role and use that as props for section

Comment: So my question then is whether "section@role" is tied to "section" simply because of a naming convention?  Or will that reappear as a property of all of "section"'s siblings?

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes, just a naming convention. It will not be passed down to every single sibling inside of section. Just to section itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this capture what you're looking for?  It seems to handle the case given, but I might be missing something.

```js
const objToConvert = {"article": [{"section": [{"title": {"content": "some simple content", "content@id": "1"}, "title@id": "title test"}], "section@role": "Testing"}]}

const convert = (obj) =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((curr, key) => obj[key] instanceof Array 
    ? Object.assign(curr, {type: key, props: curr.props, children: obj[key].map(convert)})
    : obj[key] instanceof Object
      ? Object.assign(curr, {type: key, props: Object.assign(curr.props, obj[key])})
      :  Object.assign(curr, {props: Object.assign(curr.props, {[key]: obj[key]})})
  , {props: {}})

 console.log(convert(objToConvert))
```

There is likely some clean-up to do.  If nothing else, I don't like all the instances of `obj[key]` in that function.  But I leave the clean-up as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Comment: Wow, truly thank you for your help. I have to spend some time understanding this snippet. Really nice implementation